# clickable image button in java without xml in android

Tags: java, android

I want to make image button in java class without using XML(dynamic UI).

I can make this but I can't connect to onClick void.

Can anybody help me?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LayoutParams params =
            new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TableRow table = new TableRow(this);
    table.setOrientation(TableRow.VERTICAL);


    ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this);
    ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
    ib.setLayoutParams(params);
    table.addView(ib);

    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams=
            new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    this.addContentView(table, layoutParams);

}
public void onClick(View v){

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"This button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign `OnClickListener` before using it

If you are implementing `OnClickListener` in the activity then use (I believe you are because you have `onClick` method defined)

```
ib.setOnClickListener(this);
```

If not then do this

```
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(){
        // Do as required
    }
});
```

Comment: please post the complete error? Which method is not resolved?

Comment: ib.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v){
                             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"clickable button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

Comment: setpnclicklistener bold with red coler and eror said:cannot resolve method

Comment: my fault. "c" should be "C". Use `setOnClickListener` (capital c)

Answer (score 1):

you missed `ib.setOnClickListener(...);`. If your activity implements View.OnClickListener then it would be

`ib.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: i do but this gave error with this comment:cannot resolve method